# Communicate with client-side application via PHP or JavaScript (Intranet)

Tags: php, web-applications, client, client-server, hardware-interface

I'm new inquirer but I've been around for a long time here at SO. I need some advice with a system my team and I are developing for a project.

**TLDR: Our web-app wants to send commands to a client-side applications. I know this is insecure, but it's for intranet use only. Is there a way to send shell-commands to the client-machine from our web-app in the browser? Maybe a Firefox extension of some sort?**

Basically, we're supposed to have a cloud-based web-application (PHP-based) able to work with devices (smartcard readers) attached to client machines. In short, the GUI for the system is built using web-technologies.

To give a clear picture, imagine that you have a laptop and you want to be able to use your Barcode Scanner device (attached via USB) in conjunction with the POS-application you have running in your browser.

The web-app is meant to be hosted on the cloud, but we can control the initial setup of the laptops and tablets that will be used to access our web-app.

Currently, we have a daemon installed and running on our client-side devices. This daemon acts like an HTTP server and controls the USB-attached device from a browser-window (we send it HTTP URLs, like http://127.0.0.1/scan). The daemon accepts commands if addressed as either localhost or using the actual client-machine's IP.

I believe the previous developer created this daemon with the hope of directly sending HTTP requests from the cloud-hosted application.

The main problem with this is the fact that most times, our team will be accessing the internet via an access point, so the router would assign the client-machines a local IP address. Our web-app won't know who to address its commands to.

Since the staff that will be using this will be deployed anywhere, we can't control the router configurations of whatever AP they're using to access our web-app. So NAT is out.

So far, we've come up with 1 solution for this:

We write an additional daemon (alongside the device-driver one) that interprets messages from the browser and sends them to the client's localhost (the emulated httpserver of the device-driver daemon). So now, our only issue is how our web-app, from the browser, will be able to 'talk' to our interpreter script/application.

Is there any way to send shell-commands to client-side from a web-app? I know this is a major security hole, but it'll be within our power to make sure that both the server and client don't run any malicious actions.

Or maybe we can have our web-app write to a client-hosted xml or txt file, and our interpreter daemon simply reads that xml or txt file?

Someone mentioned ActiveX in another thread I found while researching about this issue. Any thoughts on this?

Last resort would be to create a Firefox extension that does the interaction with the device-driver daemon. We do not like this solution, since on some tablets, we won't be using firefox as the browser.

Client-machines will either be Windows laptops or Raspberry Pi's (running Raspbian ARM LINUX)

Thanks!

Comment: too much text, summarize and add some code?